# Swift - Thread: 1 signal SIGABRT - xCode7 IOS 9

Tags: swift, parse-platform, afnetworking, ios9, xcode7

I am getting error in my AppDelegate.swift file, and i have no idea what the error is. I have created a new project, added Parse SDK, and the frameworks from the docs.
[image]

This is what is happening when opening the view controller:

[image]

This is the output i get:

> 2015-09-23 18:44:15.711 TestSocializeMeNEWForIOS9[13142:481060]
>   -[NSBlockOperation copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8813400660 2015-09-23 18:44:15.724
>   TestSocializeMeNEWForIOS9[13142:481060] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[NSBlockOperation copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x7f8813400660'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f9cbf65 **exceptionPreprocess + 165  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x000000011165ddeb objc_exception_throw + 48  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x000000010f9d458d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] +
>   205   3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f921f7a
>   ___forwarding_** + 970    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f921b28 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120  5   libobjc.A.dylib
>   0x000000011166bf90 _object_set_associative_reference + 78     6
>   TestSocializeMeNEWForIOS9           0x000000010e4e2c6b
>   _TFE25TestSocializeMeNEWForIOS9CSo11UIImageViewsP33_9321A4DB8B4DA2BD54B7080AA3592C6F24af_requestImageOperationT9operationGSqCSo11NSOperation_7requestGSqCSo12NSURLRequest__
>   + 171     7   TestSocializeMeNEWForIOS9           0x000000010e4e36be _TFE25TestSocializeMeNEWForIOS9CSo11UIImageView22setImageWithUrlRequestfS0_FTCSo12NSURLRequest16placeHolderImageGSqCSo7UIImage_7successGSqFT7requestGSqS1__8responseGSqCSo13NSURLResponse_5imageS2_9fromCacheSb_T__7failureGSqFT7requestGSqS1__8responseGSqS3__5errorCSo7NSError_T___T_ + 1246   8   TestSocializeMeNEWForIOS9           0x000000010e4e3acf _TToFE25TestSocializeMeNEWForIOS9CSo11UIImageView22setImageWithUrlRequestfS0_FTCSo12NSURLRequest16placeHolderImageGSqCSo7UIImage_7successGSqFT7requestGSqS1__8responseGSqCSo13NSURLResponse_5imageS2_9fromCacheSb_T__7failureGSqFT7requestGSqS1__8responseGSqS3__5errorCSo7NSError_T___T_ + 543  9   TestSocializeMeNEWForIOS9           0x000000010e4e310f _TFE25TestSocializeMeNEWForIOS9CSo11UIImageView15setImageWithUrlfS0_FTCSo5NSURL16placeHolderImageGSqCSo7UIImage__T_
>   + 911     10  TestSocializeMeNEWForIOS9           0x000000010e4e31ab _TToFE25TestSocializeMeNEWForIOS9CSo11UIImageView15setImageWithUrlfS0_FTCSo5NSURL16placeHolderImageGSqCSo7UIImage__T_
>   + 75  11  TestSocializeMeNEWForIOS9           0x000000010e4ea0d3 _TFC25TestSocializeMeNEWForIOS918HomeViewController14collectionViewfS0_FTCSo16UICollectionView22cellForItemAtIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_CSo20UICollectionViewCell
>   + 3107    12  TestSocializeMeNEWForIOS9           0x000000010e4ea21f _TToFC25TestSocializeMeNEWForIOS918HomeViewController14collectionViewfS0_FTCSo16UICollectionView22cellForItemAtIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_CSo20UICollectionViewCell
>   + 79  13  UIKit                               0x00000001109efcf1 -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:isFocused:]
>   + 481     14  UIKit                               0x00000001109f210c -[UICollectionView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 4242   15  UIKit                               0x00000001109f6871 -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews] + 247     16  UIKit
>   0x000000011029711c -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:]
>   + 710     17  QuartzCore                          0x000000010ec3d36a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146     18  QuartzCore                          0x000000010ec31bd0 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE +
>   366   19  QuartzCore                          0x000000010ec31a4e
>   _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24    20  QuartzCore                          0x000000010ec261d5
>   _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 277   21  QuartzCore                          0x000000010ec539f0
>   _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 508    22  QuartzCore                          0x000000010ec54154
>   _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92     23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f8f79d7
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 23    24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f8f7947
>   __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391  25  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f8ed59b __CFRunLoopRun + 1147    26  CoreFoundation
>   0x000000010f8ece98 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488     27  GraphicsServices
>   0x0000000112986ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161  28  UIKit
>   0x00000001101e6676 UIApplicationMain + 171    29 
>   TestSocializeMeNEWForIOS9           0x000000010e4e1ffd main + 109     30 
>   libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011629b92d start + 1 )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException (lldb)

And here is the output as a image:
[image]

Does anyone have any idea what i can do here?

Comment: Do you have anything on your storyboards?

Comment: @spacemonkey - Yes, this is a application i have been working on for 2 weeks++. This happened after updating to xCode 7.

Comment: Check all of your storyboard outlet connections to make sure they're all still connected to something in code. If you deleted or changed anything and left one outlet "live" but not connected at both ends you'll get that error message.